# How to resize image in itext in java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

This is my source code.

```
  Document document = new Document();
    String txtVehNo = "";
    String fDate = "", tDate = "", remtype = "0";
    String fileName = "Reminders_" + Utility.sysDate("yyyy_MM_dd") + ".pdf";
    String asDate = Utility.sysDate("dd/MM/yyyy");
    ArrayList<ReminderPDF> reminderPDFs = null;
    UserDetails userDetails = null;
    String txtMarNo = "";
    String formattedDate = "";
    String address = "";



    Blob imageBlob = null;
    byte[] imageBytes = new byte[0];

    try {
        txtVehNo = request.getParameter("txtVehNo2");
        fDate = request.getParameter("txtDate3");
        tDate = request.getParameter("txtDate4");
        remtype = request.getParameter("remtype");
        txtMarNo = request.getParameter("txtMarNo");

        if (txtVehNo != null && txtVehNo != "") {

            reminderPDFs = DataManagerBean.downloadRemindersForRequirementLetter(txtVehNo, remtype);


        } else if (txtMarNo != null && txtMarNo != "") {

            reminderPDFs = DataManagerBean.downloadRemindersForRequirementLetterByMarNo(txtMarNo, remtype);


        } else {

            reminderPDFs = DataManagerBean.downloadRemindersForRequirementLetter(fDate, tDate, remtype);


        }
        if (reminderPDFs.size() > 0) {

            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
            //PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(fileName));
            document.open();
            document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
            document.setMargins(85, 85, 85, 85);
            for (int i = 0; i < reminderPDFs.size(); i++) {
                String adrstr[] = reminderPDFs.get(i).address.split("\r\n");

                address = reminderPDFs.get(i).address.replaceAll(adrstr[adrstr.length - 1], "");
                document.newPage();
                Paragraph[] paragraph = new Paragraph[8];
                paragraph[0] = new Paragraph(new Phrase(reminderPDFs.get(i).mainHeader, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 12, Font.BOLD)));
                paragraph[0].setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
                document.add(paragraph[0]);
                paragraph[1] = new Paragraph(new Phrase(reminderPDFs.get(i).subHeader, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 11)));
                paragraph[1].setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
                document.add(paragraph[1]);
                if (reminderPDFs.get(i).print.equals("Y")) {
                    paragraph[2] = new Paragraph(new Phrase("(Reprint)", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 10)));
                } else {
                    paragraph[2] = new Paragraph(new Phrase("", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 11)));
                }
                paragraph[2].setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
                document.add(paragraph[2]);
                paragraph[3] = new Paragraph(new Phrase("Date : " + reminderPDFs.get(i).asDate, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 11)));
                paragraph[3].setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
                document.add(paragraph[3]);
                paragraph[4] = new Paragraph(new Phrase(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 12, Font.BOLD)));
                paragraph[4].setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                document.add(paragraph[4]);
                paragraph[5] = new Paragraph(new Phrase(address, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 11, Font.BOLD)));
                paragraph[5].setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                document.add(paragraph[5]);
                paragraph[6] = new Paragraph(new Phrase("\n" + adrstr[adrstr.length - 1], FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 11, Font.PLAIN)));
                paragraph[6].setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                document.add(paragraph[6]);
                paragraph[7] = new Paragraph(new Phrase(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 12, Font.BOLD)));
                paragraph[7].setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                document.add(paragraph[7]);

                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
                table.setWidthPercentage(100);


                formattedDate = Utility.dateFormatter(reminderPDFs.get(i).dol, "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MM-yyyy");

                table.addCell(new Phrase("Vehicle No: " + reminderPDFs.get(i).vehno, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 11)));
                table.addCell(new Phrase("MAR No       : " + reminderPDFs.get(i).marno, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 11)));
                table.addCell(new Phrase("Policy No : " + reminderPDFs.get(i).policyno, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 11)));
                table.addCell(new Phrase("Date of Loss : " + formattedDate, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 11)));
                document.add(table);

                Paragraph[] paragraph2 = new Paragraph[3];
                paragraph2[0] = new Paragraph(new Phrase(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 12, Font.BOLD)));
                paragraph2[0].setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                document.add(paragraph2[0]);

                String[] docs = reminderPDFs.get(i).content.split("\r\n");

                paragraph2[1] = new Paragraph(new Phrase(docs[0], FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 11)));
                paragraph2[1].setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
                document.add(paragraph2[1]);
                paragraph2[2] = new Paragraph(new Phrase(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 12, Font.BOLD)));
                paragraph2[2].setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                document.add(paragraph2[2]);


                // if (reminderPDFs.get(i).docs.length() > 0) {
                int k = 1;
                for (int j = 1; j < docs.length; j++) {
                    if (!docs[j].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                        document.add(new Paragraph(new Phrase("          " + k + ". " + docs[j].trim(), FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 11))));
                        k++;
                    }
                }
                // }

                Paragraph[] paragraph3 = new Paragraph[7];
                paragraph3[0] = new Paragraph(new Phrase(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 14, Font.BOLD)));
                paragraph3[0].setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                document.add(paragraph3[0]);

                paragraph3[1] = new Paragraph(new Phrase("Thank You,", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 11)));
                paragraph3[1].setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                document.add(paragraph3[1]);

                paragraph3[2] = new Paragraph(new Phrase("Yours Faithfully,", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 11)));
                paragraph3[2].setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                document.add(paragraph3[2]);

                paragraph3[3] = new Paragraph(new Phrase("Union Assurance General Ltd", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 11, Font.BOLD)));
                paragraph3[3].setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                document.add(paragraph3[3]);

                paragraph3[4] = new Paragraph(new Phrase(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 12, Font.BOLD)));
                paragraph3[4].setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                document.add(paragraph3[4]);


                imageBlob = DataManagerBean.getESignature(reminderPDFs.get(i).createdUser);
                if (imageBlob != null) {
                    imageBytes = imageBlob.getBytes(1, (int) imageBlob.length());
                    Image img = Image.getInstance(imageBytes);
                    float width = img.getWidth();
                    float hight = img.getHeight();
                    if (width > 200 || hight > 100) {
//                        img.scaleAbsoluteWidth(200);
//                        img.scaleAbsoluteHeight(100);
 //                       img.scaleAbsolute(200f, 100f);
                        img.scaleToFit(200f, 100f);
                    }
                    width = img.getScaledWidth();
                    hight = img.getScaledHeight();
                    document.add(img);
                }

                userDetails = UserBean.getUserDetailsByUserId(reminderPDFs.get(i).createdUser);

                paragraph3[5] = new Paragraph(new Phrase((userDetails.getuFName().concat(" ")).concat(userDetails.getuLName()), FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 11)));
                paragraph3[5].setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                document.add(paragraph3[5]);


                paragraph3[6] = new Paragraph(new Phrase(userDetails.getDesig(), FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 11)));
                paragraph3[6].setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                document.add(paragraph3[6]);


                //DataManagerBean.printStatusUpdate(reminderPDFs.get(i).rmid, "Y");
            }
            document.close();

            response.sendRedirect("Reminders.jsp");

        } else {
            if (txtVehNo != null && txtVehNo != "") {
                response.sendRedirect("Reminders.jsp?msgtype=3&msg=No Records for Policy/Vehicle No. - " + txtVehNo);
            } else if (txtMarNo != null && txtMarNo != "") {
                response.sendRedirect("Reminders.jsp?msgtype=4&msg=No Records for Mar No. - " + txtMarNo);
            } else if (fDate != null && fDate != "") {
                response.sendRedirect("Reminders.jsp?msgtype=5&msg=No Records between " + fDate + " to " + tDate);
            }
        }
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        SystemMessage.getInstance().writeMessage("ERROR : DownloadRequirements.jsp - " + e.toString());
    } finally {
        try {
            //reminderPDFs = null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
```

I tried   
  **img.scaleAbsoluteWidth(200);**
          
              **img.scaleAbsoluteHeight(100);**
          
              **img.scaleAbsolute(200f, 100f);**
          
              **img.scaleToFit(200f, 100f);** 
But non of this resizing the image. 

When I debug the code I get *width=200 and height= 100* for value too. I guess that means it's height and width changed. 
Please let me know what is the issue in here. 

THANK YOU.

**Note Later**

*Issues wasn't any of these methods. Issue was image not compatible with that size. After I set size to 100,50 imaged resized perfectly.*

Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your allegation "none of this is resizing the image" is wrong, and you are using the wrong methods to get the width and height of the image. Take a look at [chapter 2 of my book](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/c/5c637ac-79b4-4abe-bbed-8c72ef6a0c61/samplechapter2.pdf):

> There are different ways to change the dimensions of an image:
>
> - The width and height parameters of `scaleToFit()` define the maximum dimensions of the image. If the width/height ratio differs from the
>     aspect ratio of the image, either the width, or the height, will be
>     smaller than the corresponding parameter of this method.
> - The width and height parameters will be respected when using `scaleAbsolute()`. The resulting image risks being stretched in the X
>     or Y direction if you don’t choose the parameters wisely. You can also
>     use `scaleAbsoluteWidth()` and `scaleAbsoluteHeight()`.
> - `scalePercent()` comes in two versions: one with two parameters, a percentage for the width and a percentage for the height; and another
>     with only one parameter, a percentage that will be applied equally to
>     the width and the height.
>
> It’s a common misconception that resizing images in iText also changes
>   the quality of the image. It’s important to understand that iText
>   takes the image as is: iText doesn’t change the number of pixels in
>   the image.

There are many examples that **prove** that these methods effectively change the size of the image in the document.

If you continue reading the documentation, you discover another problem in your code:

> When creating an Image instance from a file, you won’t always know its
>   dimensions before or even after scaling it. You can get the width and
>   height of the image with these methods:
>
> - `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` are inherited from the `Rectangle` object. They return the original height and width of the image.
> - `getPlainWidth()` and `getPlainHeight()` return the width and height after scaling. These are the dimensions of the image used to print it
>     on a page.
> - `getScaledWidth()` and `getScaledHeight()` return the width and height needed to print the image. These dimensions are equal to the
>     plain width and height, except in cases where the image is rotated.

In your code, you get the *original* dimensions of the image. You *change* the dimensions of the image, and then you ask for the *original* dimensions. It shouldn't surprise you that you don't get different dimensions when asking for the original dimensions instead of the original dimensions.

Comment: Define: "Image is not resizing", If the return value of `getScaledWidth()` and `getScaledHeight()` changes, then you should see the effect on the page. I have tested this in many examples, and it always works just fine.

Comment: Note that the code snippet you shared is incomplete: it can never work! You create a `Document` but you don't create a `PdfWriter`. You should never share a code snippet that doesn't correspond with your actual code if you want an answer to your question.

Comment: For instance: looking at your code, I see that you're changing the size inside an `if` statement. Maybe the code inside that `if` statement is never reached.

Comment: Well, as I can't reproduce the problem, I can't help you. Actually, I don't think anyone can reproduce the problem, so I think no one can help. Seems like you are the only one experiencing the problem, because everyone who followed the instructions of the book was successful in resizing images.

Comment: Nobody can help you because nobody believes you (you don't provide proof for you allegation).

Comment: That's not a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). You have used up all the patience I have. If you have a support contract, contact iText Software for help. If you don't have a support contract, there are thousand of other developers on Stack Overflow here to help you. My guess is that they are all being very silent because you don't help them to help you. The problem you describe simply doesn't exist in iText 5.5.10.

Comment: Yes, you really don't understand that I can not reproduce your problem, not do I see any error in your code when I read it line by line. You **say** that the image is not resized, but I have no proof whatsoever that this is true. The methods you use are the methods from my book. More than 20K developers read that book. Hundred thousands of developers used those methods without having the problem you describe. What would you think if you were in my place? Would you believe the single developer who claims that "it doesn't work?" Put yourself in my place and you should understand.

Comment: Customers get access to a ticketing system where they can share confidential documents under NDA with the iText developers. If you're not paying for your use of iText, you are at the mercy of voluntary help. I don't think you'll get voluntary help if you're not helpful. You're not helpful because you don't share your PDF, your image, and so on. If you'd share your PDF, we'd be able to look at the internal PDF syntax. That internal syntax should show the values returned by `getScaledWidth()` and `getScaledHeight()` proving that your allegation that the image isn't resized is wrong.